# How to subscribe to global method which called

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have globalvars.ts and I added global method. How can I subscribe this method in called ts page

globalvars.ts;

```
httpgetmethod(url:string)
{
  var veri;   
  var headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json' );
  headers.append('Authorization' , 'Bearer '+ "");
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

  this.http.get(url, options)
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log( data['_body']);
    veri=data['_body'];
    veri = veri.replace(/\\/g, "");
    veri = JSON.parse(veri);
    return veri;

  });
```

profile.ts;

globalvars.httpgetmethod("http://...../api/profile/me").subscribe;

I would like to subscribe here

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you re after is a service in Angular .

A simple Angular Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HEROES } from './mock-heroes';

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
  getHeroes(): Hero[] {
    return HEROES;
  }
}
```

Include in App like

```
@NgModule({
  //other metadata properties
  providers: [HeroService]
})
```

Used in Component like

```
constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }
```

More on [**Services**](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4) and [**this**](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/services)

**UPDATE**

**Service**

```
getUser(user:string){
    return this.client.get('https://api.github.com/users/'+user);
  }
```

**Component**

```
 constructor(
private service: AngularService) {

    this.weatherService.getUser(term)
      .subscribe((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        this.result = result;
      });

  }
```

Comment: Thanks but you cant understand me. I used this tutorial. I want to only subscribe this method when called

Comment: @AhmetemreCETIN that is the reason the gave the other link too , you need not subscribe it in the service method you just need to return there and subscribe in component